# Faça um programa em python que descubra para que valor o lim (1 + 1/n)^n, n-> +inf, coverge

Tags: python

```
n = 1
y = lim(1+1/n)*n
for i in range(lim(1+1/n*n) 
  t = y*i
  print(t)
```

Estou tentando fazer assim, se puderem apontar o que eu estou fazendo de errado

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Primeiro você não fechou os parênteses é não colocou os dois pontos do escopo no `for`.

É segundo que você não determinou nenhum "lim".

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).